# The user loads the app for the first time display this page?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When a user loads the app for the first time show this page. This should be simple but I got confused on how to do this. I know how to create routes and link them. 
Do I need to create an index route ?

```
Router.map(function() {
   //Show this route first
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index route is there by default.  You should just implement `templates/index.hbs` and it will be rendered.

Comment: So I can run command "ember g route index" and this will automatically display the index.hbs content first or should I just manually create index.hbs in templates folder?

Comment: @icode you can do it either way, but just creating index.hbs in templates folder is enough

Comment: [ref from guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/tutorial/routes-and-templates/#toc_an-index-route) about index routes